# How to write in a next line with turtle in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
for i in range(0, len(all_keys)):
    if i == 4:
        break

    elem = dict1[all_keys[i]]

    output = elem + ": " + str(all_keys[i])

    print(output)

    write(output, font = style, align = "right")

    del dict1[all_keys[i]]
```

How do I make it so each iteration of the "for" cycle it writes in a new line, because right now it writes it on top of eachother.

Comment: perhaps adding `"\n"` at the end of the line will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you need to use turtle commands to move to the next line of output.  Specifically, you need to return the X coordinate to the left edge and move the Y coordinate down by the font height:

```
from turtle import *

DICTIONARY = {'one': 'uno', 'two': 'dos', 'three': 'tres'}

FONT_SIZE = 24
STYLE = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

penup()

for key, element in DICTIONARY.items():

    output = element + ': ' + key

    write(output, font=STYLE)

    goto(0, ycor() - FONT_SIZE)

mainloop()
```

[image]